# Check internet speed continuously with java

Tags: java, performance, connection, connectivity

Really couldn't find nothing on the internet about this, so will ask here, hope you can help me.

I want to check internets speed continously with java (in mb/s). Like speedtest and other external websites are working. What I've got so far just to check internets connectivity, but how to really check my internets speed?

I do not need full code or something, just point me at direction and I will try to work this out!

Comment: @simo54 Unfortunately, no. 5 years old question with expired links.

Comment: jspeedtest still exists